# Remove Mac OS partition on 2011/2012 Macbook Air

Tags: windows, macbook

My 2011/2012 MacBook Air is currently bootcamped with a Mac and Windows 7 partition. How do I remove the Mac partition? I never use it and I heard battery life is better when you're only running on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When booting the MacBook hold down Cmd+R

This will put you into Recovery Mode or download a Recovery Image if it is not already present. From here you can access the Disk Utility to remove the OS X partition.